# Android Studio Canvas DrawText substitute

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently making an app in Android studio and im making a grid, and in each cell of the grid, i am drawing text. However, I want to try and find a way to store and modify the text later using it's coordinates and itself so that when they touch it, I can change it. Is there any substitutes to use? Here is what draw looks like in Kotlin

`canvas?.drawText("0", x, y, paint)`

Answer (score 0):

`drawText` is just a way to... well, draw some text! However you store your data (cell's text contents and *x* and *y* coordinates) you're still going to be calling that function to actually draw that text at the required position.

Probably the simplest way is to just define a class to represent a cell:

```
// you could add more properties if you like, e.g. the coordinates of the cell area
data class Cell(var text: String = "", var textX: Float = 0, var textY: Float = 0)
```

then create a collection of those, and just iterate over that when you're drawing your view:

```
// Initialise this with the cells you need - just using a basic list,
// you'll need a way to determine the index of a specific cell when e.g. updating one
val grid: List<Cell>

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas?.run {
        grid.forEach { cell ->
            drawText(cell.text, cell.textX, cell.textY, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

and when you update a cell's `text`, call `invalidate()` to make the view redraw itself, so it calls `onDraw` and uses the new data.

```
private fun setCellText(cellIndex: Int, text: String) {
    // you'd probably want to handle out-of-range indices too
    grid[cellIndex].text = text
}
```

---

Your other alternative is to use a bunch of `TextView`s and update their contents - you can also set an `OnClickListener` on them instead of handling touches yourself, and having to work out which cell is being touched. Depends what you want to do and how big your grid is